# Is 10 a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

How 10 is a constant polynomial
since it can be written as $10+(2-2+2-2+2-2+2-2..........)$ and thus having infinitely many terms. Also from Wikipedia's definition a polynomial is an expression consisting of variables (also called indeterminates) and coefficients, that involves only the operations of addition, subtraction, multiplication, and non-negative integer exponents of variables.
My expression of 10 also satisfying the definition but contains infinite terms

Comment: It can't be written that way, since the sum you've written doesn't converge. Also just because ten can be written as *not a polynomial* wouldn't mean that ten isn't still an integer and thus a constant polynomial with integer coefficients.

Comment: The series doesn't actually converge. The two aren't equal.

Comment: All are saying that series written wouldn't converge. But for 10x is a Polynomial we all know and it can be written as 5x+5x and 5x+5x is also a polynomial and it also doesn't converge. Isn't this analogous to my question

Comment: There are no non finite series involved in defining polynomials. Where is this coming from?

Comment: $5x+5x$ isn't a good analogy for what you are asking... $5x+5x$ is a sum with two things in it... that's far simpler a notion than an infinite sum... The infinite sum $2-2+2-2+2+ \dots $ has some more details to be examined. You can find some details [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandi%27s_series)

Comment: 10 cannot be written as $ 10+(2-2+2-2+2-2+2-2..........)$ since the expression $2-2+2-2+2-2+2-2..........$ is meaningless. You must properly define everything or you end up with vague statements that lead to confusion without having a logical basis to build on.

Comment: "5x+5x is also a polynomial and it also doesn't converge" What?

Comment: Ya 5x+5x is a polynomial and it doesn't converge and 10+(2-2+2-2.....) Is not converging and thus be a polynomial, but why not

Comment: @user629353 "5x+5x is a polynomial and it doesn't converge" I don't think you know what ["converge" means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)).

Comment: $$10=0x^3+0x^2+0x+10$$
$10$ is a polynomial

Comment: Are you asking about the **decimal representation** of $10$? In which case $10=1\cdot  10^1 + 0\cdot 10^0$ which looks like a polynomial to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are lots of silly ways to write $10$ (ignoring the fact that what you've written doesn't really mean anything). For example, $$10=5-\sin(\pi)+3!+e^{i\pi}.$$ But none of this changes the fact that *one of the ways* to write $10$ is, well, "$10$" - and it's the fact that it *can* be written in such a way that makes it a polynomial. We don't care about the existence of *other* ways to write it. Similarly, an integer $a$ is even if $a$ *can be* written as $2\cdot b$ for some integer $b$; we can write $12$ as both $2\cdot 6$ and $3\cdot 5-1-2!$, and the fact that the former works means that $12$ is even regardless of the silliness of the latter.

Comment: I hate to break it to you, but $3\cdot 5-1-1=15-2=13 \neq 12$

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan Bah ...

Answer (score 0):

If we want to be very precise, we can use the precise definition of a polynomial. [One definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/295171/40119) is that a polynomial (with coefficients that are real numbers) is a sequence $(a_0, a_1, a_2, \ldots)$ of real numbers such that $a_k = 0$ for all sufficiently large integers $k$.

By this definition, the number 10 is technically not a polynomial. However, people will often use the symbol 10 to denote the polynomial $(10,0,0,\ldots)$. This is an example of a symbol being "overloaded", which happens sometimes in math. Hopefully the meaning will always be clear from the context.